# how to check current_user's roles and permission in postgresSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have created a user in PostgreSQL.

then I have created a role
and granted the role to the user.

now I want to write row level policy for the current user with some role permission

sql:--

```
create user martin;
create role role_manager;

grant role_manager to martin;

CREATE POLICY student_rls_policy
student
FOR ALL
TO role_manager
USING (name = **?**);
```

Now  I want to pass current_user role at?

Comment: See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-rowsecurity.html

Comment: So you have a table `student` with a text column `name`, and you want your user (role) `martin` to see only the rows where the name is `'martin'`?